# How to keep current HtmlElement active and change its properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I have a simple class that listens click and draws two points on the page.

If first point is not exist it is drawn. When second point is present it should be changed after each click.

I dislike this part of code:

```
this.point2.element.style.left = `${e.x}px`;
this.point2.element.style.top = `${e.y}px`;
```

Full code:

```
export class Kizda {
    private point1: { element: HTMLElement; pointMeter: Point };
    private point2: { element: HTMLElement; pointMeter: Point };

    getPoints() {
        return { point1: this.point1, point2: this.point2 };
    }

    action(e: MouseEvent): void {
        const point = this.getMouseMPoint(e);

        function createPoint(color: string): HTMLElement {
            let pointSize = 12;
            let pointElement = document.createElement('div');
            pointElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            pointElement.style.width = `${pointSize}px`;
            pointElement.style.height = `${pointSize}px`;
            pointElement.style.left = `${e.x}px`;
            pointElement.style.top = `${e.y}px`;
            pointElement.style.background = color;
            pointElement.style.borderRadius = '50%';

            document.body.append(pointElement);

            return pointElement;
        }

        if (!this.point1) {
            this.point1 = { pointMeter: point, element: createPoint('red') };
            return;
        }

        if (!this.point2) {
            this.point2 = { pointMeter: point, element: createPoint('green') };
            return;

        } else {
            this.point2.element.style.left = `${e.x}px`;
            this.point2.element.style.top = `${e.y}px`;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Unlike Stack Overflow we do not answer `How to` questions. because they indicate the code is not working as expected. On Code Review the code must be working before we can answer. If your code is working please change the title to indicate what the code does. It would be helpful for you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are some repetitions in the current implementation, which can be refactored and the code will become clearer. For example:

- Use a custom `type` or `interface` for the private members.

```js
interface MyPoint { // of course, choose a better name than MyPoint, which matches your context!
  element: HTMLElement; 
  pointMeter: Point;
}

export class Kizda {
  private point1: MyPoint;
  private point2: MyPoint;

  ...
}
```

- The `createPoint` function produces only a part of the point object, but it can indeed produce instances of `MyPoint`. And it does not need to be nested inside the `action` function:

```js
private createPoint(e: MouseEvent, color: string): MyPoint {
  const size = '12px';
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  const style = element.style;

  style.position = 'absolute';
  style.width = size;
  style.height = size;
  style.background = color;
  style.borderRadius = '50%';

  this.setCoordinates(element, e);

  document.body.append(element);

  const pointMeter = this.getMouseMPoint(e);
  return { element, pointMeter };
}

private setCoordinates(point: HTMLElement, e: MouseEvent): void {
  const style = point.style;
  style.left = `${e.x}px`;
  style.top = `${e.y}px`;
}
```

- Finally, adjust the implementation of the `action` method by reusing the refactored items:

```js
public action(e: MouseEvent): void {
  if (!this.point1) {
    this.point1 = this.createPoint(e, 'red');
  }
  else if (!this.point2) {
    this.point2 = this.createPoint(e, 'green');
  }
  else {
    this.setCoordinates(this.point2.element, e);
  }
}
```